# Retrieve values from mysql that do not exist, nor the ones nearby

Tags: mysql

I'm looking for values that not only don't exist in a given table, but where related values also do not exist.  Valid values are two-dimensional between -5 and 5, for a total of 121 values (given other constraints).

So, for the former, I have something along these lines:

```
select x,y from (
  select
   v.x,
   w.y
  from 
   (select '-5' as x union all select '-4' union all select '-3' union all select '-2' union all select '-1' union all select '0' union all select '1' union all select '2' union all select '3' union all select '4' union all select '5') as v
  join
   (select '-5' as y union all select '-4' union all select '-3' union all select '-2' union all select '-1' union all select '0' union all select '1' union all select '2' union all select '3' union all select '4' union all select '5') as w
  left join
   (select x,y,id from building where body_id = ?) as b on v.x = b.x and w.y = b.y
  where
   b.id is null
) as t
```

This gives me a list of x,y co-ordinates that do not have a "building" on them.  However, what I want to find out is if there is any x,y where not only is that empty, but the ones surrounding it (x-1 through x+1, y-1 through y+1) are also empty.  By definition, then, any x of +/-5 and any y of +/-5 will necessarily not have all the surrounding ones empty.

Worst case scenario, I guess, is pulling the above information and searching myself on each value to see if all the surrounding ones are not found.  I ask more to use it as an excuse to learn more SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key concept for your query is this line: **on v.x = b.x and w.y = b.y**.
(From this little snippet towards the end:

```
(select x,y,id from building where body_id = ?) as b on v.x = b.x and w.y = b.y where b.id is null
```

This means you're interested only in the joins where the v.x and w.y are exactly on the building's coordinates.

It's simple to change that condition. For example, try something like this:

```
select x,y from 
(
    select v.x, w.y from 
    (
        select '-5' as x union all select '-4' union all select '-3' union all select '-2' union all select '-1' union all select '0' union all select '1' union all select '2' union all select '3' union all select '4' union all select '5'
    ) as v
    join
    (
        select '-5' as y union all select '-4' union all select '-3' union all select '-2' union all select '-1' union all select '0' union all select '1' union all select '2' union all select '3' union all select '4' union all select '5'
    ) as w
    left join    
    (
        select x,y,id from building where body_id = ?
    ) as b 
    on 
    (
        (v.x + 1 = b.x and w.y + 1= b.y) OR
        (v.x + 1 = b.x and w.y = b.y) OR
        (v.x + 1 = b.x and w.y - 1= b.y) OR
        (v.x = b.x and w.y + 1= b.y) OR
        (v.x = b.x and w.y = b.y) OR
        (v.x = b.x and w.y - 1= b.y) OR
        (v.x - 1 = b.x and w.y + 1= b.y) OR
        (v.x - 1 = b.x and w.y = b.y) OR
        (v.x - 1 = b.x and w.y - 1= b.y) 
     )
     where b.id is null
) as t
```

This won't take care of the border cases (+/-5 on x or y) as you defined them, at least, not in the way I understand your tables, but you can add additional OR and AND statements to your "on" condition.

Also, I didn't have a table or a database connection handy, so this isn't tested. There might be some small errors, but they should be easy enough to fix.

**EDIT**: 
I just realized I might've mixed up which spaces you want. It's a little confusing, since we don't see the tables you're using.

After a little thinking, I think that you most likely want a condition where you do something like this in the ON clause (I've swapped the +/- to happen on the building's position now, rather then a coordinate):

```
(b.x + 1 = v.x and b.y + 1= w.y) OR
(b.x + 1 = v.x and b.y = w.y) OR
(b.x + 1 = v.x and b.y - 1= w.y) OR
(b.x = v.x     and b.y + 1= w.y) OR
(b.x = v.x     and b.y = w.y) OR
(b.x = v.x     and b.y - 1= w.y) OR
(b.x - 1 = v.x and b.y + 1= w.y) OR
(b.x - 1 = v.x and b.y = w.y) OR
(b.x - 1 = v.x and b.y - 1= w.y)
```